# Chained combos in register form Joomla 2.5

Tags: forms, joomla, registration, joomla2.5

Good morning.
I'm using joomla 2.5, I need add extra fields to my user form registration, I use user-profile plugin and I add 2 extra fields SQL type, at this point all is ok, but I need, that this fields work like chained combo  i.e: when I select a **Departamento** (Department) I need the field **Municipio** (Municipalitie) just display the Municipalities that belonging to that department.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify in which language you wanted this done in. There's a jquery plugin  you could use by [Mike Tuupola](http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects) which does just this. You might want to check it out.

Comment: I suppose is a good idea do this functionality using Ajax to retreive the municipalities that belongs to X department. The trouble is that I need integrate this with the Joomla 2.5 form registration...